Creating a cutable body from a fit-point spline outline in Autodesk Fusion
I have an outline of a shape that I created with fit-point splines. This appears closed to me (as in, it creates a continuous shape), but when I try to extrude, I cannot select it. When I try to use Open/Close Spline Curve, it does not work correctly (see image below). For a brief description: it omits one section of the shape, and has a curve going off into space. I suspect this is because the curve was originally made in multiple parts and not joined correctly, but so far my attempts to join them have not worked. None of my internet research has been helpful, and my computer has prevented me from installing a plugin to convert the splines to arcs and lines.

I have been able to create an extrusion that is a zero-thickness edge of the shape, but since I want to include internal features, that will not work for me. I would like to eventually get this cut (with internal features/holes/etc) out of acrylic from some CNC service. Any help, or anything I'm missing, would be very appreciated. Thanks!
